# Como puedo Poner una imagen de fondo en css

Tags: html, css, wordpress, elementor, fondo

Hola tengo un inconveniente estoy intentando poner una imagen de fondo , pero al colocar el color en una parte me pone un excedente el cual no es lo deseado utilice un psedoelemento before para colocar el fondo pero no se como pudiera corregir ese pequeño error adjunto mi Html y css y un capture con el problema

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

---

Código html :

```
 <div id=imagen>
     <p>fgfh<p>
     </div>
<div class="card">
  <div class="container">
    <h4><b>John Doe</b></h4> 
    <p>Architect & Engineer</p> 
  </div>
</div>

<style>
#imagen{
   background-image: url(http://localhost/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2021/09/factores-a-considerar-escuela.jpg);
  
   height: 200px;
   width: 350px;
   
}
#imagen:after{
  
    content: '';
    position:absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
   
    background-color: rgba(210,223,33,0.9);
}
.card {
 
  box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
  transition: 0.3s;
  width:350px;
}

.card:hover {
  box-shadow: 0 8px 16px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
}

.container 
height: 200px;    
  padding: 2px 16px;
}
</style>
```

---

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

lo que necesito corregir es ese excedente que esta señalado lo quiero quitar

Comment: si ese es el codigo html el problema que tengo es que el color de fondo de la imagen se pasa del tamaño de la imagen y crea un excedente en la parte inferior

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simplemente define en el elemento `after` una medida especifica similar a la de la imagen, no definas 100% de alto o ancho, define por ejemplo:

```
#imagen::after{  
    content: '';
    position:absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    height: 200px;
    width: 350px;  
    background-color: rgba(210,223,33,0.3);
}
```

[image: [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/6XIV7.png]

Comment: Vale muchas gracias ya lo voy a probar

Comment: si me funciono amigo muchas gracias voy a tomar en cuenta el consejo que me diste enante de editar la pregunta.

Comment: ok ya la marque

Answer (score 0):

```
<style>
#imagen{
   background-image: url(http://localhost/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2021/09/factores-a-considerar-escuela.jpg);
  
   height: 200px;
   width: 350px;
   
}
#imagen:after{
  
    content: '';
    position:absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
   
    background-color: rgba(210,223,33,0.9);
}
.card {
 
  box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
  transition: 0.3s;
  width:350px;
}

.card:hover {
  box-shadow: 0 8px 16px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
}

.container 
height: 200px;    
  padding: 2px 16px;
}
</style>
```

Luego dentro de tu body

```
<div id=imagen>
    
<div class="card">
  <div class="container">
    <h4><b>John Doe</b></h4> 
    <p>Architect & Engineer</p> 
  </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Por favor intenta

Comment: Si esto no soluciona tu problema, por favor intenta explicarnos con más detalles lo que deseas obtener.

Comment: ok listo ya lo intento

Comment: no me funciono ya te explico en si que es lo que necesito

Comment: Estas utilizando bootstrap?

Comment: no lo estoy haciendo en html y css

Answer (score 0):

La solución que plantea Jorgesys es lo que necesitas, pero aun debes retocar algunas cosas.
Si yo fuera tu lo haría de la siguiente manera:

```css
 <style>
        body {
            background-color: #222;
            font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
        }
        .card {
            background-image: url(https://www.collinsdictionary.com/images/thumb/school_309241295_250.jpg);
            background-size: cover;
            overflow: hidden;
            width: 350px;
            background-color: #FAFAFA;            
            border-radius:5px;
            -webkit-box-shadow: 5px 5px 15px 5px rgba(0,0,0,0.46); 
            box-shadow: 5px 5px 15px 5px rgba(0,0,0,0.46);
        }
  
        .card .card-header {
            background: rgba(210,223,33,0.7);
            overflow: hidden;
            height:200px;
            z-index: 2;
        }
        .card .card-body {
            padding: 10px;
            background:#FFF;
        }
    </style>
```

```html
  <div class="card">
        <div class="card-header"></div>
        <div class="card-body">
            <h3>John Doe</h6>
            <p>Architec & Enginer</p>
        </div>
    </div>
```